Conceptual doubt related to motion of two blocks on an incline
I was solving the following question:

In the arrangement shown in the figure all surfaces are smooth. Select the correct alternative(s)

(A) for any value of θ acceleration of A and B are equal
(B) contact force between the two blocks is zero if $\frac{m_A}{m_B}$ = $tanθ$
(C) contact force between the blocks is zero for any value of $m_A$ or $m_B$
(D) normal reactions exerted by the wedge on the blocks are equal

My Attempt: I assumed the accelerations of block A and block B as $a_A$ and $a_B$. I have drawn the free body diagrams of the two blocks separately as shown below

So, based on the diagrams I applied newton's second law to write the following equations
$$\color{blue}{N + m_Agsinθ = m_Aa_A} (1) $$
$$\color{blue}{m_Bgsinθ - N = m_Ba_B} (2) $$
Now on adding (1) and (2) we get
$$\color{red}{(m_A + m_B)gsinθ = m_Aa_A + m_Ba_B} (3)$$
Now, as acceleration of blocks is independent of mass and assuming they will maintain contact both will have an acceleration of 'gsinθ' along the incline
i.e  $a_A = a_B = gsinθ$
So, from this logic substituting these values in equation (1), (2) and (3) we get N = 0.
Therefore, we arrive at the conclusion that both the blocks have equal accelerations irrespective of θ and the contact force between them is zero irrespective of values of $m_A$ or $m_B$. So the answer for the question would be options (A) and (C) which is correct according to the answer key.
Is my logic for the solution correct?
My Doubt here: If the accelerations of the blocks along the incline are the same then they should maintain contact irrespective of their masses as they are released.
So, how can the normal contact force between them come out to be zero? From what I have been told I know that normal contact force is present when two surfaces are in contact. But the fact that it is zero (i.e N = 0) reflects that they don't maintain contact. Where am I missing to interpret the scenario?

Contact between them does not necessarily imply a normal force between them. A normal force between them will only appear if they are pressed together - that is, if one exerts a force on the other. The purpose of the normal force would then be to prevent one block from breaking through the other block.
But if both objects move exactly equally (equal speeds, which will be the case here when the accelerations and starting speeds are assumed equal), then they are not being pressed together. Just like how two skydivers who fall at equal speeds can be close and even touch each other lightly without applying forces to each other.

Okay... I have a doubt in your statement regarding pressing.  Like what do you mean by pressing?So, why do we consider the normal force on a block kept on a frictionless wedge as there also no external agent is pushing the block and no pressing is there?

@Chetan By the blocks being "pressed together" I mean when they exert pushing forces on each other. A single block on a frictionless wedge is exerting a pushing force perpendicularly on the wedge - that would be its weight (gravitational force) - and hence a normal force appears perpendicularly up from the wedge surface in that case.

As you mentioned in the case of a single block on a frictionless wedge, the block exerts a push force that is its weight on the wedge and hence a normal force appears then in case of two blocks as in my question, the block B would also push block A right? because there is a component of block A's weight along the incline(i.e mₐgsinθ) which pushes block B so block B would exert a normal force up the incline on A. But it doesn't happen like that. Why? Can you please explain

@Chetan Block A wants to fall straight down due to gravity. The wedge is in the way, so a normal force from the wedge appears and causes the block to move at an angle, sliding down. Block B also wants to fall straight down due to gravity. The wedge is again in the way, so a normal force from the wedge appears and causes the block to move at an angle, sliding down. Now, it just so happens that they are sliding down with the same speed and acceleration! Block B is not faster than block A, so why would it push in block A?

@Chetan Here is another way to think about it: Lift the two objects and drop them, and they will fall equally fast, because gravity accelerates objects equally regardless of size, shape and masses. If you hold them close together so they are in contact and then let go, then they will still fall equally fast, so one will not be pushing on the other - there will be no force between them. What is happening on the wedge in your case is the same - they are "falling" at an angle down along the wedge at equal speeds and accelerations while they just happen to be in contact.

yeah right.. got the idea.. we can also observe from a frame which has the same acceleration of blocks and then it would simply become the case of two blocks at rest sitting beside each other and hence no normal force would arise to prevent penetration cuz no pressing is there. Am I right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Chetan Yep, I agree.

okay thanks for clearing my doubt


If the accelerations of the blocks along the incline are the same then
they should maintain contact irrespective of their masses as they are
released. So, how can the normal contact force between them come out
to be zero?

Consider what happen if we take the extreme case of the slope being vertical and the two blocks are in free fall. As Galileo allegedly demonstrated when he dropped two objects with different weights from the Tower Of Pisa, both objects fall at the same rate. If they are in contact, neither object is pushing the other and there is no contact force or reaction contact force. The same applies to this question.
P.S. Imagine the two blocks are made of rubber and are sitting on a perfectly frictionless surface.  If the two blocks are pushed hard against each other so that they are compressed, they will expand again as soon as they are released, reducing the contact force to zero. There is however a semantic issue here that arose in another related question. Does "smooth surface" mean frictionless. If it does, why not just say frictionless? It seems to be a bad habit of old text books.

Suppose the two masses were sitting in contact on the table top. They would exert normal forces on each other just strong enough to keep themselves from penetrating into each other. But not strong enough to push themselves apart.
If you press them together, they press themselves apart with an equal force.
If they just sit, it takes a force of $0$ to keep them from penetrating into each other.
